# How I can use Tk Entry with def correctly?

Tags: python, function, tkinter, append, label

I'm learning Python myself and I have a problem with `tk.Entry` labels. I made def for them and here's a problem that list_1 and List_2 are not appending as I expected. The program has to work in that way, after pressing button, words from `WEntry` and `MEntry` will be added to lists, shown on the screen next to "queue" label and Entry labels will be cleaned. Cleaning entry labels is ok, it worked, but why appending doesn't?

```
def Queue_Insert():
   Word = WEntry.get()
   Mean = MEntry.get()
   List_1.append(Word)
   List_2.append(Mean)
   WEntry.delete(0, 'end')
   MEntry.delete(0, 'end')

WMButton = tk.Button(root, width=25, text ="Insert to queue", font =("Courier",8), bg ="peru", command=Queue_Insert) 
WMButton.grid(row=1, column=4, padx = 10)
```

I tried with `str(WEntry.get())` but it didn't change. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Did you try printing ```LIst_1```&```List_2``` in terminal ?
I mean how did you exactly get to know that it is not working?

Comment: There is no information related to `List_1`, `List_2`, `MEntry` and `WEntry`.  It is better to provide a [mre].

Comment: Im using Spyder from Anaconda, and there's a window showing every single structure. Values called List_1 and List_2 are lists type but they are called "empty".